# C# MethodInvoker - how to call method in thread in class A from class B?

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I've not been able to find anything that deals with my situation and I'm not sure how to handle it.  The setup:

1. Form1: select a number of activities and select go.
2. Form1 creates ClassA which makes Form2 programatically with a number of progressbars based on the number of tasks.
3. Form1 calls method in ClassB to do required activity, and passes instance of itself to Class B.
4. Class B starts thread to do processing and returns.

What I want to do is call Form1.ClassA.updateProgressBar(index) from ClassB every so often.

The MehtodInvoker seems to be the right way to go but I'm not sure how to go about it.  I'm thinking of something along the lines of...

```
form.Invoke((MehtodInvoker) delegate { 
     Form1.prog.incProgressBar(name);
})
```

Where prog is ClassA...

Thanks,
Reza

Comment: Why doesn't the code you posted work?

Comment: prog is not recognized as part of Form1

Comment: here's some more code http://pastebin.com/LQu8TG46  with what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

ClassB is running in the non-UI thread so you need to make sure progress bar is updated in Form1's UI thread.

```
in Form1:

public void UpdateProgressBar(int index)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<int>(i => UpdateProgressBar(i)), index);
    }
    else
    {
        prog.updateProgressBar(index);
    }
}



in ClassB:

form1.UpdateProgressBar(index);
```

Comment: will this all me to call it anytime without any of this methodinvoker stuff?

Comment: @reza: yes. notice all progress bar updating logic is in the Form1. provided ClassB has ref to Form1 instace, it can update progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Default visibility of properties and class members is private, i.e. prog is private and not accessible.

Comment: yup, this was the key to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
form.Invoke((MehtodInvoker) delegate { 
    form.prog.incProgressBar(name);
})
```

Comment: problem was that I needed to make prog public.  working now. someone posted that as a solution but now that solution is gone.

Comment: I remember this answer, but I don't know why it's gone. What about ivan's answer? It seems to be a good one for me.

Comment: I deleted my post by mistake. Sorry. It's now back.